# Kernel oops when executing function to read hardware registers

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm referencing [this answer for crash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21855668/988207) help in analyzing this bit of code which caused problems.  The context for everyone, I'm working a character driver, which will act as a pass through from user space directly to the hardware, for the ahci driver.  I'm modifying the ahci driver accordingly for this purpose.

I'm starting small.  I want to peek at the port registers for the HBA port 0 of the AHCI HBA on my VM.  My character driver ioctl code:

```
switch (cmd) {
    case AHCIP_GPORT_REG:
        pPciDev = pci_get_device(0x8086, 0x2829, NULL);

        if (pPciDev) {
            /* This will set ret to the value that it needs to be.  This
             * is true of __put_user() too */
            if ((ret = __get_user(off, (u32*)obj))) {
                printk(KERN_INFO "unable to read from user space\n");
                goto ioctl_quick_out;
            }

            reg = get_port_reg(&pPciDev->dev, off);
            if ((ret = __put_user(reg, (u32*)obj)))
            {
                printk(KERN_INFO "Unable to write to user space\n");
            }

            pci_dev_put(pPciDev);
        }

        // This break wasn't in the code when it crashed
        break;

    default:
        // POSIX compliance with this one (REF of LDD3)
        ret = -ENOTTY;
}
```

The code from my modified version of ahci.c which this character driver calls into:

```
u32 get_port_reg(struct device *dev, u32 off)
{
    struct Scsi_Host *shost = class_to_shost(dev);
    struct ata_port *ap = ata_shost_to_port(shost);
    void __iomem *port_mmio = ahci_port_base(ap);

    return ioread32(port_mmio + off);
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL(get_port_reg);
```

The kernel oops that this caused, happened here:

```
PID: 3357   TASK: ffff88011c9b7500  CPU: 0   COMMAND: "peek"
 #0 [ffff8800abfc79f0] machine_kexec at ffffffff8103b5bb
 #1 [ffff8800abfc7a50] crash_kexec at ffffffff810c9852
 #2 [ffff8800abfc7b20] oops_end at ffffffff8152e0f0
 #3 [ffff8800abfc7b50] no_context at ffffffff8104c80b
 #4 [ffff8800abfc7ba0] __bad_area_nosemaphore at ffffffff8104ca95
 #5 [ffff8800abfc7bf0] bad_area at ffffffff8104cbbe
 #6 [ffff8800abfc7c20] __do_page_fault at ffffffff8104d36f
 #7 [ffff8800abfc7d40] do_page_fault at ffffffff8153003e
 #8 [ffff8800abfc7d70] page_fault at ffffffff8152d3f5
    [exception RIP: get_port_reg+18]
    RIP: ffffffffa03c4cd2  RSP: ffff8800abfc7e28  RFLAGS: 00010246
    RAX: 0000000000020101  RBX: 00007fff17273960  RCX: ffffffff812b0710
    RDX: ffff88011ddd5000  RSI: 0000000000000000  RDI: ffff88011ddd5090
    RBP: ffff8800abfc7e28   R8: 0000000000000000   R9: 0000000000000000
    R10: 00000000000007d5  R11: 0000000000000006  R12: ffff88011ddd5000
    R13: 0000000000000000  R14: 0000000000000000  R15: 0000000000000000
    ORIG_RAX: ffffffffffffffff  CS: 0010  SS: 0018
```

As you can see, the instruction pointer was `get_port_reg+18`.  Since this function is quite small, here's the full disassembly

```
crash> dis get_port_reg
0xffffffffa03c4cc0 <get_port_reg>:      push   %rbp
0xffffffffa03c4cc1 <get_port_reg+1>:    mov    %rsp,%rbp
0xffffffffa03c4cc4 <get_port_reg+4>:    nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
0xffffffffa03c4cc9 <get_port_reg+9>:    mov    0x240(%rdi),%rax
0xffffffffa03c4cd0 <get_port_reg+16>:   mov    %esi,%esi
0xffffffffa03c4cd2 <get_port_reg+18>:   mov    0x2838(%rax),%rdx
0xffffffffa03c4cd9 <get_port_reg+25>:   mov    0x28(%rax),%eax
0xffffffffa03c4cdc <get_port_reg+28>:   mov    0x10(%rdx),%rdx
0xffffffffa03c4ce0 <get_port_reg+32>:   shl    $0x7,%eax
0xffffffffa03c4ce3 <get_port_reg+35>:   mov    %eax,%eax
0xffffffffa03c4ce5 <get_port_reg+37>:   add    0x28(%rdx),%rax
0xffffffffa03c4ce9 <get_port_reg+41>:   lea    0x100(%rax,%rsi,1),%rdi
0xffffffffa03c4cf1 <get_port_reg+49>:   callq  0xffffffff8129dde0 <ioread32>
0xffffffffa03c4cf6 <get_port_reg+54>:   leaveq 
0xffffffffa03c4cf7 <get_port_reg+55>:   retq   
0xffffffffa03c4cf8 <get_port_reg+56>:   nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
```

As you might have guessed, I'm something of an assembly neophyte.  Which line of code would be `get_port_reg+18`?  I'm puzzled because I'm calling functions on each line of that function but the only call I see is to `ioread32()`.

For reference, I've modeled my function `get_port_reg` after `ahci_show_port_cmd()` [within the same file](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+*/drivers/ata/ahci.c#L798).  I could not think of any other means of getting the `struct pci_dev` structure necessary on which this is to operate.  Am I making bad use of `get_pci_device()` and `pci_dev_put()`?  Is this not the issue at all?

Thanks for any help
Andy

Comment: `pci_get_device()` is probably returns a pci device, while you need corresponding SCSI host device -- they have different classes.

Comment: Look at `ata_pci_remove_one`: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/ata/libata-core.c#L6314 it shows how to get `ata_host` from PCI device and getting `ata_port` from it should be simple.

Comment: It seems that problem is here - ata_shost_to_port. I can tell you just from technical point of view, without code understanding: Function class_to_shost is basically a container_of, so it assumes that the struct device (dev) is embedded into struct Scsi_host, so it cast dev to Scsi_host appropriately. Next your code tries to dereference shost to get ata_port (*(struct ata_port **)&host->hostdata[0]). And boom ... it seems that here is page_fault happened. SO that mean that probably there is a trash instead of struct Scsi_host ...

Answer (score 3):

I am going to post my own answer.  The two commentators of my question have put me onto the correct path for fixing this.  As I mentioned, my approach was to do something which I'd seen done elsewhere in the ahci driver (ahci.c).  Basically, the assumption was simple, [this function in ahci.c](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+*/drivers/ata/ahci.c#L798) required a `struct device*` and from that was able to get the `ata_port` information that was required.  I'd seen, in ahci.c, that the author had done `struct device* = &pdev->dev;` occasionally.  In other words, I figured that the *dev* member of `struct pci_dev` was getting me what I needed.  I was apparently unaware of "class types" or something similar (see @myaut's first comment).  @alexhoppus essentially draws the same/similar conclusion based on the code and disassembly which I posted.

The fix which I have employed, and which does work nicely, is as follows:

```
/* ioctl code in character driver */
switch (cmd) {
    case AHCIP_GPORT_REG:
        pPciDev = pci_get_device(0x8086, 0x2829, NULL);

        if (pPciDev) {
            struct ata_host *pHost = NULL;
            struct ata_port *pPort = NULL;
            printk(KERN_INFO "found the PCI device\n");
            /* Get the devices driver data */
            pHost = pci_get_drvdata(pPciDev);
            if (!pHost) {
                ret = -EFAULT;
                goto ioctl_valid_pci_dev_out;
            }

            /* for this test, we'll use just port 0 */
            pPort = pHost->ports[0];
            if (!pPort) {
                ret = -EFAULT;
                goto ioctl_valid_pci_dev_out;
            }

            /* This will set ret to the value that it needs to be.  This
             * is true of __put_user() too */
            if ((ret = __get_user(off, (u32*)obj))) {
                printk(KERN_INFO "unable to read from user space\n");
                goto ioctl_valid_pci_dev_out;
            }

            reg = get_port_reg(pPort, off);
            if ((ret = __put_user(reg, (u32*)obj)))
            {
                printk(KERN_INFO "Unable to write to user space\n");
            }
        }

        break;

    default:
        // POSIX compliance with this one (REF of LDD3)
        ret = -ENOTTY;
}
```

The ahci driver was modified thusly as well

```
u32 get_port_reg(struct ata_port* pPort, u32 off)
{
    void __iomem *port_mmio = ahci_port_base(pPort);

    return ioread32(port_mmio + off);
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL(get_port_reg);
```

Though this has fixed the issue for me, I would really appreciate someone explaining to me what is placed in `(struct pci_dev)device.dev.p->driver_data.  I can use, and have, the Linux cross referencing tools to see the data types.  What is supposed to be stored in`struct device_private`?  [This is the structure](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+*/drivers/base/base.h#L80) which I'm now using to get the data I need.  I'd truly appreciate someone commenting on this answer to explain that one.

Thanks to @myaut and @alexhoppus